# Audio Manager Bluetooth not working properly on Samsung S9, Note8

Tags: android, audio, android-bluetooth, samsung-mobile, android-audiomanager

This is the code of I have to handle the audio:

```
 fun setSpeakerValue(value: SIPManager.AUDIO) {
        speaker = value
        when (value) {
            SIPManager.AUDIO.EAR_PIECE -> {
                binding.callItemIconSpeaker.setImageResource(R.drawable.speaker_off)
                if (Build.BRAND.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains("oneplus")) {
                    audioManager?.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
                } else audioManager?.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL
                audioManager?.stopBluetoothSco()
                audioManager?.isBluetoothScoOn = false
                audioManager?.isSpeakerphoneOn = false
                speaker = SIPManager.AUDIO.EAR_PIECE
            }
            SIPManager.AUDIO.SPEAKER -> {
                binding.callItemIconSpeaker.setImageResource(R.drawable.speaker_on)
                audioManager?.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
                audioManager?.stopBluetoothSco()
                audioManager?.isBluetoothScoOn = false
                audioManager?.isSpeakerphoneOn = true
                speaker = SIPManager.AUDIO.SPEAKER
            }
            SIPManager.AUDIO.BLUETOOTH -> {
                binding.callItemIconSpeaker.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_data_bluetooth)
                if (Build.BRAND.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains("huawei")) {
                    audioManager?.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
                } else audioManager?.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL
                audioManager?.startBluetoothSco()
                audioManager?.isBluetoothScoOn = true
                speaker = SIPManager.AUDIO.BLUETOOTH
            }
        }
    }
```

Now this works properly so far for all phones I tried. But for Samsung S9 and Note8 it selects Bluetooth for the first time, when my SIP call is connected.

After that changing to EAR_PIECE doesn't do anything, and then changing to Speaker it sets it to speaker and that is all.

No matter what I call it will remain blocked on Speaker.

Please help, did anyone else have this issue?

Comment: setSpeakerPhone not working on android 10 tested on pixel 2 do you know the reason?